# Zabbix and HP OpenView integration

Tags: zabbix

Did someone ever set up Zabbix to work with HP OpenView ?
[Zabbix docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/appendix/recipes) doesn't mention much information on that.

I know I have to create a media linked to a script.
In that script I have to use the `opcmsg` command but I don't understand the part which involves the database.
Can someone who ever experienced it drives me to the solution ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we have decided to create a media script which is writing output to a file.
Then that file will be monitored by a HP OpenView agent.

The steps are the following:

- Create media script which is referencing your script :

[image: media script screen]

In my case the script is named `hpov.sh`

- The location of your script has to be referenced in your server config file (zabbix_server.conf) this way : `AlertScriptsPath=/path/to/zabbix/scripts`
- Create an action which will be triggered on problems. Specify the macro you want in the first tab. The condition you want in the second one (leave as default). And finally set the third tab "Operations" like that:

[image: zabbix action operations]

You are free to change Users who are concerned

- As the documentation says, link that media script to a user of your choice

That's it !

Answer (score 1):

You are missing [media script doc](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script). Parse input in your media script and process it with 'opcmsg'.

Try to find similar alert scripts (concept, not code) for your inspiration - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script

And finally please publish your script with documentation (I recommend Github + Zabbix share).